# Refreshing data from SQL in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, refresh

I'm really confused about how i can refresh data that i use in my powerBi.

The data come from a server in SQL, at first time i choosed to use DirectQuery as importation mode, after a litle bit of time i observed that its took time when i want to change things like measure or representations.

So i opted to change directquery to importation in order to gain time.

I would like to know how can i get the newest data from my sql server automaticly, because i have line which is added every day, would i use accrementiel refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Just set up a daily refresh schedule in the Power BI Service. If you have big data with a long history you might also benefit from incremental refresh, but that's alread an optimization step.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of power bi gate way ?

Keep your dashboards and reports up to date by connecting to your on-premises data sources without the need to move the data. (https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/)

You just need to install power bi gateway to your server.

Then you can visit power bi service -> settings -> manage gateway . You can setup new gateway here.
[image]

Once you create connection you can schedule refresh time with your UTC time.

[image]

**Note:** you need to buy power bi pro or premium licence for that. Pro licence has 8 times refreshes per day and premium has about 48 times per day(premium is very expensive) .

And their is feature called incremental refresh, you have to setup it prom power bi dashboard.

It may take 10-20 minutes to refresh data set.(mentioned in power bi site)

Answer (score 0):

Hi do you using Power BI desktop?
click on your page not visual, on the visualization you will see,option called **page refresh**. set this *On*.
set **Refresh type** to *Auto page refresh*.
set **Refresh this page every** the value you want(*seconds,minutes,hours,day*).

[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1fXK.jpg)